# How to delete all nodes and all relationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I know a lot of similar questions have been asked. But it seems like the answers can't solve my problem.
I have a very big graph, about 1 Million nodes and 3 million relations. When I try to delete them using following statements:

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r
```

Then server is crashed. OK, I added LIMIT:

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
WITH n,r LIMIT 1000000
DELETE n,r
```

The server will not crash, **but** an exception shows up:

```
org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: Node record Node[1578965,used=false,rel=662269,prop=-1,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light] still has relationships
```

I guess the **LIMIT 1000000** will stop my deleting on relationship. Then it turns to delete the node. which cause that exception. Am I right? because I don't quite understand the process of **LIMIT 1000000**.

So what should I do? I don't want to drop the database file each time I need to clear my graph. Setting a larger memory space might help, but the size of my graph also might become larger. The crash will happen eventually.

---

Thanks for all your reply. I tried both your method. An exception **"Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure"** will show up in the second time I run the statement:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n LIMIT 1000000
DETACH DELETE n
```

or this statement:

```
MATCH ()-[r]-()
WITH r
LIMIT 1000000
DELETE r
```

I give up. I think I'd better delete all files in my folder. That's a simple way for me.

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the batch size, i.e. the limit?

Answer (score 5):

On Neo4j 2.3 you can use

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n LIMIT 1000000
DETACH DELETE n
```

Otherwise, you can try limiting by nodes (only good if each individual node does not have a huge number of relations):

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n LIMIT 1000000
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r
```

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is delete relationships first and then nodes.

relationships

```
MATCH ()-[r]-()
WITH r
LIMIT 1000000
DELETE r
```

nodes

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n
LIMIT 1000000
DELETE n
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete all relationship with:

> start r=relationship(*) delete r;

And Delete All Nodes:

```
MATCH (n) WITH n LIMIT 1000000 DETACH DELETE n.
```